# Android Studio & Emulator slow performance in Android Studio on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, performance

On my mac Android Studio is usable, however on my Linux Ultrabook, normally a fast machine, Android Studio and the Emulator are so slow (5 mins to start, one response or less per minute) that they are unusable.

On OSX I remember the main fix for that was about HAX but I don't see any messages in the log window about it and am not sure if that is really the issue.

I installed java 7u79 for the software to work.

I followed the steps here https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator and my hardware seems to support it all, i.e.

```
$ sudo kvm-ok 
[sudo] password for durrantm: 
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
$ egrep -c ' lm ' /proc/cpuinfo
4
$  uname -m
x86_64
13:35:40 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Downloads/android-studio 
$  sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

Not sure where to put options though I tried run -> Launch options
[image]
But still slow.

Comment: Did you find any solution? :(